# Error messages in my blackjack cli in ruby

Tags: ruby, blackjack

I'm working on a learn.co lab Blackjack cli the line is https://learn.co/tracks/web-development-fundamentals/intro-to-ruby/looping/blackjack-cli?batch_id=166&track_id=10415 however of the 15 examples required to pass i keep getting an error for 6 i'am mainly having trouble with the initial_round method and the hit? method.

[i keep getting an error in the initial round method asking me to call on the display_card_total method to print the sum of cards and the hit? confuses me a little as to what exact its asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVyx.png)

```
def deal_card
 rand(11) + 1
end

def display_card_total(card)
    puts "Your cards add up to #{card}"
end

def prompt_user
  puts "Type 'h' to hit or 's' to stay"
end

def get_user_input
  gets.chomp
end

def end_game(card_total)
    puts "Sorry, you hit #{card_total}. Thanks for playing!"
end

def initial_round
    deal_card
    deal_card
    return deal_card + deal_card
    puts display_card_total
end

def hit?
    prompt_user
end

def invalid_command
  puts "Please enter a valid command"
end
```

hope this is enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't followed the assignment.

It specifies that the `hit?` method should take an argument of the current card total, so it should be...

```
  def hit?(current_card_total)
```

It then specified that you should do `prompt_user` *and* `get_user_input` and then test the result for "h" or "s" or other and take appropriate action.

If you do a "h" for hit, the current_card_total will be increased, otherwise if you do an "s" it's unchanged, but you need to return the value, regardless of whether it's changed or not.

If the user enters something else beside "h" or "s" you call the `invalid_command` method and prompt again for the correct value (`prompt_user`) and you can try to get a response again with `get_user_input`

So, something like this...

```
def hit?(current_card_value)
  prompt_user
  user_input = get_user_input
  while user_input != "h" && user_input != "s"
    invalid_command
    prompt_user
    user_input = get_user_input
  end
  if user_input == "h"
    current_card_value += deal_card
  end
  return current_card_value
end
```

There's a few things wrong with your `initial_deal` but just to start with, you need to keep track of the deal_card results in a variable

```
current_card_total = deal_card
current_card_total += deal_card
```

That way `current_card_total` has the accumulated total. Just doing

```
deal_card
deal_Card
```

doesn't store the results of `deal_card` anywhere.

Comment: that makes so much sense i really feel as if at times i over think i need to work on my ability to read error messages more

Comment: i'm still having trouble with initial_round